# What is the supremum of 1-dim Hausdorff measure of the nodal set of Neumann eigenfunction $u$ for planar convex domain

Tags: ca.classical-analysis-and-odes, eigenvalues, geometric-measure-theory, eigenvector

All descriptions of this question are limited to 2-dimension for simplicity. Recently, I read some papers on the nodal set of Laplacian eigenfunctions. Denote $\Sigma=\{u(x)=0\}$ be the nodal set of a fixed eigenfunction, recently Logunov proved such an upper bound $\mathcal{H}^1(\Sigma)\leq c\lambda^\alpha$, where $\lambda$ is the corresponding eigenvalue of $u$ and $\alpha >1$ is a constant, and $\mathcal{H}^1$ is the 1-dim Hausdorff measure. Therefore, a natural question is that can we get a sharp upper bound for some specific settings?

Hence I try to solve such a question:
$$
\sup_{u,\Omega} \mathcal{H}^1(u^{-1}(0)),
$$
where the supremum is taken over any planar convex region $\Omega\subset\mathbb{R}^2$ with diam$(\Omega)=2$ and any Neumann eigenfunction $u$ w.r.t. $\mu_1(\Omega)$, the first positive Neumann eigenvalue for $\Omega$. Also, it's interesting if we change the constraint on diameter into area.

I've tried to solve it by modifying the method given by Logunov, but it seems impossible to get the conclusion I want.

I'm sure this question must already be solved, but I can't find any reference on it. Can someone share some references on this question with me? I'll be appreciated a lot!

Comment: Just to clarify: you're only interested in the value of the supremum, or in finding a domain which might maximize the nodal set?

Comment: @LeoMoos Hello Leo, actually I'm interested in both these two questions! I think that to find the value of the supremum, we must know some geometry information, so the specific domain also attracts me a lot!

Comment: It's a bit outside my area of expertise, so I'm not sure what is reasonable, but I would first try to look at symmetric domains, say discs, squares, thin rectangles, and ellipses. That should give you a better idea of what the value might be, and how to go about proving it. As a side remark, some of the tags you picked seem a bit odd; I would suggest trying to find some that your question a bit better.

Comment: Thank you! I'll try to solve it by following this idea.